# Real time video stream cropping & re compositing: your thoughts on this?

Tags: video, video-streaming, real-time, video-processing, video-editing

I'm digging some information for an upcoming personal/hobby project and I thought Stack Overflow would be a nice place to discuss the feasibility of the project.

*In a few words:*

I got a video stream (from an HDMI capture card), I would like to take a few **parts of that stream and re-arrange them into a new video**.

*In a few more words:*

- be able to selectively crop some areas (hardcoded locations could do the trick) from a video stream
- use the cropped video parts (of the original video) for compositing a new video by rearranging those elements and maybe adding a few other things
- being able to do this with minimal latency (Less than a second could be okay)
- being able to preview locally the output video in "real time"
- be able to switch between "scenes" (different video cropping areas etc.)

As pictures speak better than confused explanations, here is one:

[image: schema]

Is it something in the realm of the possibilities for a senior dev (backend and mobile) with small experience in media manipulation ? or is it a really big challenge right here ? is the "real time" constraints bearable for this kind of task ?

what kind language/tool would you direct to ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can easily take live video and draw it to a canvas.. and then stream the canvas to the internet. For example https://record.a.video (Github: https://github.com/apivideo/recordavideo) uses the full camera and full screen at 30 FPS. There's no reason you cant crop that data they way you are asking.